# Installing qmcpy in Python

Tags: python, pip, package

I failed to install the "Quasi Monte Carlo Framework in Python 3" *qmcpy*.

I tried it with `pip install qmcpy`, `conda install qmcpy`.
I also downloaded the [tar.gz file from the project page](https://pypi.org/project/qmcpy/#files) and tried to install it manually. Nothing worked.

I got a long error output (I have even deleted here some part, because it would be too large):

```
Building wheels for collected packages: qmcpy
  Building wheel for qmcpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ob2g99v7\\qmcpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ob2g99v7\\qmcpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rvxfgit_'
       cwd: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ob2g99v7\qmcpy\
  Complete output (102 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy
  copying qmcpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol
  copying qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\sobol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol
  copying qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol
  running egg_info
  writing qmcpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to qmcpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to qmcpy.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to qmcpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'qmcpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'qmcpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies
  copying qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies\sobol_mat.21201.32.lsb.npy -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies
  copying qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies\sobol_mat.21201.32.msb.npy -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies
  copying qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies\sobol_mat.51.30.msb.npy -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\qmcpy\discrete_distribution\sobol\generating_matricies
  running build_ext
  building 'qmcpy.discrete_distribution.c_lib.c_lib' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

How do I get this package installed?

Comment: Did you read the last line `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.` and follow instructions there?

Comment: Also from your question it not clear, which of the 3 install methods gave you the error-output. Please make this clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the last line of the output where it says `error:` you see the issue and its resolution:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

It gives you a link to download the required:

[Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

If you go to that link and click the *download button* then run the installer you have finally **fulfilled the prerequisites**.
Then you can start the build again and this error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools that the error message is complaining about you not having.

Comment: This is not an answer, rather a comment. Please read [answer] and explain how to solve the issue.